# mySql - extract key from array of objects

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7

Given an array of jsons I  want to extract a given key from object object

**e.g:**

extract 'Name' key

`'[{"Name": "Homer", "Age": 39}, {"Name": "Marge", "Age": 40}]' --->["Homer" , "Marge"]`

**My attempt**

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{"Name": "Homer", "Age": 39}, 
                      {"Name": "Marge", "Age": 40}]','$.Name');
```

returns null

Im using mysql 5.7.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need square bracketed notation such as `'$[*].Name'` while formatting the second argument as JSON value is nested within them

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{"Name": "Homer", "Age": 39}, 
                      {"Name": "Marge", "Age": 40}]','$[*].Name') AS names
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=24d24df46739a50de4f87a9913aa2ca4)</kbd>